# Hot air balloon toilet?

Tags: balloon

I have never been in Hot air balloon

But today I was wondering, what if someone in Hot air balloon wanted to pee?

how will they do it??

if there are no toilets in there, can they just do it from there to the ground? what if there was people down there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Overboard or a plastic bottle.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/41949)

Comment: @Sean Yes it does?

Comment: We normally look for more detail than this but, honestly, I'm not sure there's much more to say, here.

Answer (score 7):

The same way people solve this problem on a small boat - overboard.
(Fun fact: most large boats that do have toilets, flush them overboard as well. Our civilization isn't that averse to treating one another to our waste.)

If there are people down there, they might get a few drops of golden shower. But considering the small number of balloons in the air, your odds to get hit by bird droppings are a lot higher.

Comment: In civilized parts of the world, boats are not allowed to flush the toilet any more, and holding tanks are mandatory.  ;)

Comment: Then what I've seen of Europe (the Med) isn't civilized ;). The holding tanks get flushed out to sea the moment the boat is leaving the harbor. At least by most owners.

Comment: @Therac there is typically a minimum distance off shore at which you can pump overboard. [In the US its only 3 miles](https://www.boatus.org/study-guide/environment/waste/) which is not terribly far. In Europe the [regs range from 2 miles to never](https://www.noonsite.com/Members/val/R2009-01-16-1) but it also seems that not all boats are required to have holding tanks which makes it tricky to enforce in some places.